# Populating nicedit image plugin with dynamic list

Tags: javascript, php, image, wysiwyg, nicedit

Ive been try for ages to populate a dropdown select box with dynamic image list reading from the upload folder, without success. I do not need an upload script, that's been sorted.

Also using float instead of align, again no joy. Can anyone help or at least point me in the right direction.

Many Thanks ;-)

```
    <script>
var nicImageOptions = {
    buttons : {
        'image' : {name : 'Add Image', type : 'nicImageButton', tags : ['IMG']}
    }
    /* NICEDIT_REMOVE_START */,iconFiles : {'image' : 'image.png'}/* NICEDIT_REMOVE_END */
};
/* END CONFIG */

var nicImageButton = nicEditorAdvancedButton.extend({   
    addPane : function() {
        this.im = this.ne.selectedInstance.selElm().parentTag('IMG');
        this.addForm({
            '' : {type : 'title', txt : 'Add/Edit Image'},
            'src' : {type : 'select', txt : 'Align', options : { ### POPULATE DYNAMICALY FROM FOLDER USING PHP ###}},
            'alt' : {type : 'text', txt : 'Alt Text', style : {width: '100px'}},
            'CLASS' : {type : 'select', txt : 'FLOAT', options : {none : 'Default','left' : 'Left', 'right' : 'Right'}}
        },this.im);
    },

    submit : function(e) {
        var src = this.inputs['src'].value;
        if(src == "" || src == "http://") {
            alert("You must enter a Image URL to insert");
            return false;
        }
        this.removePane();

        if(!this.im) {
            var tmp = 'javascript:nicImTemp();';
            this.ne.nicCommand("insertImage",tmp);
            this.im = this.findElm('IMG','src',tmp);
        }
        if(this.im) {
            this.im.setAttributes({
                src : this.inputs['src'].value,
                alt : this.inputs['alt'].value,
                CLASS : this.inputs['CLASS'].value
            });
        }
    }
});

nicEditors.registerPlugin(nicPlugin,nicImageOptions);
</script>
```

############################### UPDATE

Getting there using

```
`<input type='button' onclick="nicEditors.findEditor('article').setContent('tester');" value='Change Text'`/>
```

...but when I populate setContent with my html -

```
<input type='button' onclick="nicEditors.findEditor('article').setContent('<img src="../IMAGES/s/0za4ihOuga.jpg" class="ifn" />');" value='Change Text'/>
```

I get

```
');" value='Change Text'/>
```

showing on the page and the image showing

Comment: Since when is jQuery _heavy_?

Comment: Getting there using

    <input type='button' onclick="nicEditors.findEditor('article').setContent('tester');" value='Change Text'/>

...but when I populate setContent with my html - 

    <input type='button' onclick="nicEditors.findEditor('article').setContent('<img src="../IMAGES/s/0za4ihOuga.jpg" class="ifn" />');" value='Change Text'/>

I get 

    ');" value='Change Text'/>

showing on the page and the image showing

Answer (score 0):

I have a reason.

```
/* START CONFIG */
var nicImageOptions = {
    buttons : {
        'image' : {name : 'Add Image', type : 'nicImageButton', tags : ['IMG']}
    }

};
/* END CONFIG */

var nicImageButton = nicEditorAdvancedButton.extend({   
    addPane : function() {
       var objid = document.getElementById('contentid').value;
        this.im = this.ne.selectedInstance.selElm().parentTag('IMG');
        this.addForm({
            '' : {type : 'title', txt : 'Add/Edit Image'},
            'src' : {type : 'select', txt : 'Bild', options : {none : '-'}},            
            'alt' : {type : 'text', txt : 'Alt Text', style : {width: '100px'}},
            'align' : {type : 'select', txt : 'Align', options : {none : 'Default','left' : 'Left', 'right' : 'Right'}}
        },this.im);
        this.myFrame = new bkElement('iframe').setAttributes({ width : '0px', height : '0px', frameBorder : 0, scrolling : 'no', src : 'listatt.php?id='+objid }).setStyle({border : 0}).appendTo(this.pane.pane);
    },

    submit : function(e) {

       var objid = document.getElementById('contentid').value;
       src = "/docs/content-" + objid + "/" + this.inputs['src'].value;


        this.removePane();

        if(!this.im) {
            var tmp = 'javascript:nicImTemp();';
            this.ne.nicCommand("insertImage",tmp);
            this.im = this.findElm('IMG','src',tmp);
        }
        if(this.im) {
            this.im.setAttributes({
                src : this.inputs['src'].value,
                alt : this.inputs['alt'].value,
                align : this.inputs['align'].value
            });
        }
    }
});

nicEditors.registerPlugin(nicPlugin,nicImageOptions);
```

An example.

[image]

listatt.php

```
<body>

<script>

function addOption(selectbox, text, value)
{
    var optn = document.createElement("option");
    optn.text = text;
    optn.value = value;
    selectbox.options.add(optn);
}

function addOptions(element, options)
{
    //var element = getElementById(selectbox);
    var size = options.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        addOption(element, options[i][0], options[i][1]);
    }
}

var element = parent.document.getElementById('src');
var option = new Array();
<?php
// here fill the array
$atts = $app->wiki->getAttachments($_id,'wiki');
$i = 0;
foreach ($atts as $att)
{
    echo "option[$i] = new Object();";
    echo "option[$i]['0'] = '$att[name]';";
    echo "option[$i]['1'] = '$att[name]';";
    $i++;
}
?>

addOptions(element,option);

</script>

</body>
```